# SDIO wifi card not working

Tags: networking, wireless

Got no wifi on my Tablet PC and i read that some SDIO wifi cards are causing some trouble on Linux. (got one installed in the Tablet Pc) 
I already tried some different apporaches on solving this problem but none of those worked for me so i think i need my individual fix.

dmesg | grep -i sdio has no Output.

dmesg | grep-i firm:

[    0.130661] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.371640] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    5.762936] acpi INT3496:00: [Firmware Bug]: GPIO not in correct mode, fixing
[    6.161637] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM4343A0.hcd failed with error -2

I know that bluetooth and wifi is one unit together so at least it recognises it partially (could be that i don't know enough and this is bull****)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep -i sdio` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: dmesg | grep -i firm    
The card might not even be seen if the firmware is missing.